# Error adding migration(3,4) to room database after adding new tables

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I was developing an app, where I'm using room, and I get into the need of add some migration due to I have 4 tables in my database.

My problem comes adding the Migration(3,4), which rise the following error, when add the following migrations:

```
near "'checkInDate'": syntax error (Code 1) while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST 


`DB_SHIFT_NAME` (`id` INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), `checkInDate` TEXT) 
//Create DB_SELLS
    val MIGRATION_1_2: Migration = object : Migration(1, 2) {
        override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$DB_SELLS_NAME`")
        }
    }
    //DB_SESSION
    val MIGRATION_2_3: Migration = object : Migration(2,3) {
        override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `${DB_SESSION_NAME}`")
        }
    }
    //Create DB_SHIFT
    val MIGRATION_3_4: Migration = object : Migration(3,4) {
        override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `${DB_SHIFT_NAME}` (`id` INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), `checkInDate` TEXT)")
        }
    }
```

Here my models with their DB's:

```
@Entity(tableName = Constants.DB_SESSION_NAME)
data class RegistrationData(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false) val id: Int = 1,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "tcod") val tcod: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "sessionToken") val sessionToken: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "mac_address") val mac_address:String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "serial_number") val serial_number:String
)

@Entity(tableName = Constants.DB_SELLS_NAME)
data class SellData(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false) var time: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "accepted") val accepted: Boolean,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name") val name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "quantity") var quantity: String? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "unitPrice") var unitPrice: String? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "totalPrice") var totalPrice: String? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "type_sell") val type_sell: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "type_product") val type_product: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "product_price") val product_price: String?, //This is _totalPrice
    @ColumnInfo(name = "processorTextValue") val processorTextValue: String?,
)

@Entity(tableName = Constants.DB_SHIFT_NAME)
data class ShiftData(
    //TODO: Add configuration from StartTurn: id_turno, virtual_ticket
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false) val id: Int = 1,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "checkInDate") val checkInDate: String,
)

@Entity(tableName = Constants.DB_PRODUCTS_NAME)
data class ProductData(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false) val productID: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "time") val time: String? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name") val name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "product_price") val product_price: String?, //This is _totalPrice
    @ColumnInfo(name = "maxPrice") val maxPrice: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "minPrice") val minPrice: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "type_sell") val type_sell: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "type_product") val type_product: Constants.PRODUCT_TYPES,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "imageB64") val imageB64: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "taxPercent") val taxPercent: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "flagID") val flagID: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "accepted") val accepted: Boolean? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "amountSell") val amountSell: String? = null
)
```

Regarding my Database class:

```
@Database(
    entities = [ProductData::class, SellData::class,RegistrationData::class, ShiftData::class],
    version = 4,
    exportSchema = true
)
abstract class LocalDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun dao(): CepsaDAO

}
```

And finally the build of the RoomDatabase with Dagger:

```
   @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDB(@ApplicationContext context: Context): LocalDatabase {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(
            context.applicationContext,
            LocalDatabase::class.java,
            Constants.DB_NAME
        ).addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2, MIGRATION_2_3, MIGRATION_3_4)
        .build()
    }
```

It's a little bit weird that only the migration(3,4) rise an error, being the only one which I've defined the query adding the atributes of their model.

I don't know If it's a syntax error in the query, due to I don't see it, or if I should add the atribute to the other models.

if you can experiment some simular issue and can help, take thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first issue is that PRIMARY KEY, if defined at the table level (as opposed to at the column level), must follow the column definitions.

- that is all column definitions must precede table definitions.

  - as per
  - [image]
  - https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

    - i.e. `id INTEGER` and `checkInDate TEXT` are column definitions
    - `PRIMARY KEY (id)` is a table constraint
    - with Room, at present, no table options are catered for.

You will also have an issue with the lack of specifying the NOT NULL constraint for both columns.

- Without the NOT NULL constraint, Room would then issue an exception indicating a discrepancy between what was expected and what was found. Room is strict in what it expects.
- In Kotlin if a var/val is not nullable (e.g. Int or String as opposed to the nullable Int? or String?) then it will require the `NOT NULL` constraint (in most cases).

So what you want is

```
database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `${DB_SHIFT_NAME}` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `checkInDate` TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`id`))")
```

**However**, the best way of ascertaining the correct SQL for creating the tables is to:-

1. make the changes to the `@Entity` annotated class(es).
2. Add the class(es) to the `@Database` annotation.
3. Compile the project successfully.
4. Using android View, find the **generated(java)** directory/folder and then locate the class that is the same name as the class that is annotated with `@Database` suffixed with **_Impl**

   1. *in your case **`LocalDatabase_Impl`**.*
5. In the class there will be a method called createAllTables. This will include statements that execute SQL to create the tables.
6. Copy the SQL and if you wish, in your case, replace the hard coded name with the respective variable.